# How to get the this keyword working in TypeScript for me

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

I have a question regarding Typescript an `this`:

I have two classes where one class wants to call a method from the other class:

```
class Calculator {
    foo: number;

    constructor(foo: number) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public write() {
        return "abc";
    }
}
```

The class which wahts to call the method:

```
class Game {

    calc: Calculator;

    constructor() {
        // this is working fine
        this.calc = new Calculator(1);
    }

    create() {
         for (var index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
            // here this.calc is undefined and I don't know why
        }      
    } 
}
```

Then in my create method I always get `this.calc` is `undefined`and I dont know why.

Then I'm calling it like this:

```
window.onload = () => {
    var game = new Game();
};
```

The `create` method is called via `Phaser.Game` which is a game library.

Comment: its working fine.. mostly it might be issue with exporting.. defined in one module and using it in another or something like that. Btw how do you know its undefined, what error are you getting??

Comment: @gurehbgui: where do you call "create()" method? I mean that depending on further implementation it is possible to loose "this"

Comment: I added how I call it.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your bug but in my case everything seems to be OK. "The create method is called via Phaser.Game which is a game library." - just to make sure that we are not missing anything, what is type of "this" in create() method when it gets called?

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine, here's a snippet I compiled to show that your other class can use `this.calc` to access the calculator attached to it, then I print out the value from `Calculator.write()`

```
class Calculator {
    foo: number;

    constructor(foo: number) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public write() {
        return "abc";
    }
}

class Game {

    calc: Calculator;

    constructor() {
        // this is working fine
        this.calc = new Calculator(1);
    }

    create() {
         for (var index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
            console.log(this.calc.write());  // this.calc works just fine here
        }      
    } 
}

var game = new Game();
game.create(); // this logs "abc" 5 times in the console
```

Answer (score 0):

If you getting undefinded at this, you can use :

```
var that = this.game.state.getCurrentState() as ConstructorState;
that.calc..
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference to `this` is probably being lost. Try changing method signature to bound instance variable:

```
create = () => {
     for (var index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
        // here this.calc is undefined and I don't know why
    }      
}
```